# Add all entries from one specific glossary

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

I created different glossaries to store different types of informations in my document (in the specific case there are two additional glossary types: `greek` and `nondim` other than `main` and acronyms).

```
\usepackage[toc,acronyms]{glossaries}
\newglossary[zlg]{greek}{zld}{zln}{Greek Symbols} %Greek Letters
\newglossary[nng]{nondim}{nnd}{nnn}{Non-dimensional Groups} %Non-Dimensional Numbers
```

With this what I achieve is that I have a list of glossaries used for acronyms that are added using `\gls{acronym}`, 
the standard glossary is used, for example, for Latin symbols:

```
\newglossaryentry{latin:h}{
    name=$h$,
    description={Enthalpy per unit of mass},
    sort=h
}
```

then I use the other glossaries, as an example, for greek symbols and non-dimensional groups:

```
\newglossaryentry{symb:Gamma}{
    name=$\gamma$,
    description={Generic property subjected to operators},
    sort=gamma, type=greek
}

\newglossaryentry{ndg:St}{
    name=$St$,
    description={Stokes number $\frac{18\mu_c}{\rho_p d_p^2}\frac{U}{D}$},
    sort=St, type=nondim
}
```

What I would like to achieve now is to use `\glsaddall` for specific types, in particular I would like to print all the glossaries from the `main`, `greek` and `nondim` types but not from the acronyms that instead have to show up only if explicitly called wih `\glsadd` in the text.

This is how I'm actually printing the glossaries in my document:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=main,style=long,nonumberlist,nopostdot,title={Latin Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=greek,style=long,nonumberlist,nopostdot]
\printglossary[type=nondim,style=long,nonumberlist,nopostdot]
```

but if I do not use `\glsaddall` the glossaries in `main`, `greek` and `nondim` are not showing up (not being explicitly added in the text), if I use `\glsaddall` I see correctly all the glossaries from all the types, but I see also acronyms that I did not use in the text.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\glsaddall` has an optional argument, which allows for specification which glossary types should be used:

`\glsaddall[types={main,greek,nondim}]`

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage[toc,acronyms]{glossaries}

\newglossary[zlg]{greek}{zld}{zln}{Greek Symbols} %Greek Letters
\newglossary[nng]{nondim}{nnd}{nnn}{Non-dimensional Groups} %Non-Dimensional Numbers


\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{latin:h}{
    name=$h$,
    description={Enthalpy per unit of mass},
    sort=h
}


\newglossaryentry{symb:Gamma}{
    name=$\gamma$,
    description={Generic property subjected to operators},
    sort=gamma, type=greek
}

\newglossaryentry{ndg:St}{
    name=$St$,
    description={Stokes number $\frac{18\mu_c}{\rho_p d_p^2}\frac{U}{D}$},
    sort=St, type=nondim
}

\newacronym{zdf}{ZDF}{Zweites Deutsches Fernsehen}

\begin{document}


%\glsaddall% Adds any gls - entry, e.g. acronyms
% Select only particular types: 
\glsaddall[types={main,nondim,greek}]


\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=main,style=long,nonumberlist,nopostdot,title={Latin Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=greek,style=long,nonumberlist,nopostdot]
\printglossary[type=nondim,style=long,nonumberlist,nopostdot]


\end{document}
```

[image]